# Remove all values from an array in javascript LWC

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I want to remove or delete all the values from array in javascript Lightning Web Component .
Can you suggest any approach to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: `theArray = [];`, job done. That said it depends on exactly what you want to happen and quite how the array is used. Your question is poor quality and should be [edit]ed to add more information and to show what you already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depend of what you precisely want to do and the context but for reset an array in Js you can just set the variable to an empty array :

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr = [];
```